# Sumir com um componente usando jQuery ao carregar a página. E depois aparecer ele após um determinado evento em um laço while

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um jogo de *jokenpo* e quero colocar um `while` para pedir um valor para o usuário. Preciso que quando o `document` seja carregado o `texbox` suma.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    var choice = null;  
    var vitoriaPlayer = 0;
    var vitoriaComputer = 0;


    $("#nameJogador-index").ready(function(){
        this.hide();
    });

    //Altera o nome do jogador no inicio do index_game
    $("#nameUser").text(localStorage.jogador);

    //Gera a opção do computador
    var computerChoice = Math.random();

    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "Pedra";

    }else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "Papel";

    }else {
        computerChoice = "Tesoura";

    } 

    //Evento e função responsáveis por comparar as jogadas e mostrar para o usuário
    $('#pedra, #papel, #tesoura').on('click', function(ev){

        //Atribui o valor clicado pelo usuário para variavel choice
        var choice = $(this).prop("id").toLowerCase(); 
        computerChoice = computerChoice.toLowerCase();

        if((computerChoice == choice) || (computerChoice == choice)||(computerChoice == choice)){
                $("#vencedor").text("Empate");
                $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

        }else if (choice === "pedra"){

                if (computerChoice === "tesoura"){
                    $("#vencedor").text("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");

                    vitoriaPlayer += 1;

                    $("#scoreUser").text(vitoriaPlayer);

                    $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                    $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);


        }else{
                    $("#vencedor").text("Oponente venceu");

                    vitoriaComputer += 1;

                    $("#scoreOponent").text(vitoriaComputer);

                    $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                    $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);
            }

        }else if (choice === "papel"){
                if (computerChoice === "pedra"){

                     $("#vencedor").text("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");

                     vitoriaPlayer += 1;
                     $("#scoreUser").text(vitoriaPlayer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

        }else{
                     $("#vencedor").text("Oponente venceu");

                     vitoriaComputer += 1;

                     $("#scoreOponent").text(vitoriaComputer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

            }

        }else if (choice === "tesoura") {

                if (computerChoice === "pedra"){
                     $("#vencedor").text("Oponente venceu");

                     vitoriaComputer += 1;

                     $("#scoreOponent").text(vitoriaComputer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

        }else{

                     $("#vencedor").text("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");

                     vitoriaPlayer += 1;

                     $("#scoreUser").text(vitoriaPlayer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);
            }

            if(vitoriaPlayer >= 3){
                alert("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");
            }else if(vitoriaComputer >=3){
                alert("Computador ganhou");
            }
        }

        //Janela modal
        ev.preventDefault();

        var id = $("a[rel=modal]").attr("href");

        var alturaTela = $(document).height();
        var larguraTela = $(window).width();

        //Colocando o fundo preto
        $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
        $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
        $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

        var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
        var top = $(window).scrollTop()+10

        $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
        $(id).show();   

        });

        $("#mascara").click( function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(".window").hide();
        });

        $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            $("#mascara").hide();
            $(".window").hide();
            });
        });
```

Código HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="nameJogador-index" placeholder="Nome do Jogador">
        <input type="submit" value="Jogar" id="jogar">  
    </div>
```

Comment: Com o código cortado não tem como reproduzir para entender como isso funciona.

Comment: Opa, e agora, ficou melhor?

Comment: Agora melhorou. =]

Comment: Mas ainda tah faltando algum código ali depois do while.

Comment: Me desculpa, tinha colocado o while mas para ter uma noção do que eu queria e não coloquei a variável para pegar o click

Comment: Se entendi, você quer que suma o formulário onde coloca o nome do jogador?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, se a jogada do usuário for igual a do computador vai gerar um empate e dai para o while rodar certo vai ter que pedir um outro valor para o usuário. Só que eu quero que esse evento seja disparado quando ocorrer o empate, caso contrário que permaneça escondido.

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir seu código aqui... dá erro.

Comment: Ficou faltando a outra parte do programa, desculpa. Sou novo aqui, ainda não me acostumei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.hide()` e o `.show()` do JQuery.

Exemplo:

```
$('#id_do_componente').hide(); //Some

$('#id_do_componente').show(); //Aparece
```

Fonte:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp